# Can this fittonia argyroneura be saved?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health

I gave my friend a fittonia that I propagated from my own plant. Since she's had it, I've been checking up on it a bit, letting her know the best light placement, etc. Almost a year since I last checked it, she showed me the plant and it looks like it's nearly dead, and I'm not even sure how I would try to save it. The leaves are tiny and shriveled, and the stem system is very thick and crawling. Any ideas? If it can't be saved, I'd also love to know what went wrong in this case. I've posted a picture of the mother plant, and a picture of my friend's plant in the current state.

[image: The problematic plant with tiny leaves and large thick stems]

[image: The original plant with busy leaves and no visible stems]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was exposed to very dry air (maybe placed near heating device?) or cold air. 
If the stems are not limp, it is completely safe to propagate it again from top cuttings to get a fresh start.